# 500 error page with no information in production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I am currently encountering couple of issues with the a rails application deployed on Linode server. The gemfile looks like below :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
     # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activeadmin',:git => "git@github.com:sadanmasroor/active_admin.git"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'roo'

group :production do
     gem 'unicorn'
end

group :development do 
    gem 'thin'
    gem 'capistrano'
end
```

Apparently there were list of issues with ActiveAdmin in the beginning mostly with activeadmin assets which I finally overcame by debugging the issues. Now the problem is that the assets precompile successfully in development and also in production ( Capistrano Assets Precompile Task) however I am getting a 500 error when accessing the index page even.

The weird part is that there is no error in production log. It just shows that the assets precompiled successfully. I have no idea what exactly is causing this issue. I have been trying to figure this thing out for almost three days now. Have tried literally everything I could to resolve it from the ActiveAdmin issues to stackoverflow and everything but no result. If I revert the code to the last stable one and than deploy everything works perfectly.

I would be very thankful to anybody who can point me to the right direction to fix this thing.

Thanks

Comment: So you have no debug info on the 500-error? Can you replicate this in development? Can you use the debugger to isolate where and when the problem occurs?

Comment: @Jesper: This is exactly the weird part. There are no errors in the development enviornment. In production there are no errors in production.log . I have also set the log level to debug i.e.  config.log_level = :debug in production.rb but still no help. Do you have any idea what exactly is causing this ? Do you think it could be because of assets pipeline ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linode, but maybe you can check logs for "upper" levels. What I mean is that, maybe the error is in something like Passenger or Apache, depending on your setup, and we should try and check those logs too.

Comment: Also, is the 500 page the one provided in your project as `/public/500.html` or another one? If it does not enter ruby, then it won't log through rails...

Comment: @Jesper: if I revert the code to the previous code which was not having activeadmin and than deploy it it works perfectly fine. My understanding is that it is because of some compilation issues in ActiveAdmin but not sure how to reach the cause of this error

Comment: @rewritten: I am getting /public/500.html one !

Comment: @rewritten's advise is really good, remove or move the 500-page to see the rails error message.

Comment: I'd have a look at a diff of the Gemfile.lock to see _exactly_ what gems change.  My guess is that one of the gems you are using is causing ruby to segfault.  I've been in situations where I get a 500 error but no stacktrace, and in my case ruby was segfaulting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending almost 2 days to fix the issue I used the old version of ActiveAdmin instead of the new latest release and everything worked like a charm.